# How to pack float in to 4 bytes (rgba) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, opengl, floating-point, bit-manipulation, glsl

Trying to wrap my head around encoding normalised float in to rgba array (four 0-255 integer values) in `JavaScript`. To be specific i'm attempting to port this `GLSL` code:

```
vec4 packFloatToVec4i(const float value) {
  const vec4 bitSh = vec4(256.0*256.0*256.0, 256.0*256.0, 256.0, 1.0);
  const vec4 bitMsk = vec4(0.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0);
  vec4 res = fract(value * bitSh);
  res -= res.xxyz * bitMsk;
  return res;
}
```

Should be fairly simple but i'm still having hard times using bitwise operations.
To my understanding applying `vec4 bitSh` to value is equivalent of doing `[value << 24, value << 16, value << 8, value]` in `JS`.
And I think I understand what bit shifting and masking should do as a concept, but it still looks like a black magic to me.

**Expected results:**

```
packFloatToVec4i(0.4242) = [0,95,151,108]
packFloatToVec4i(0.108108) = [64,246,171,27]
```

**Update** - My attempt to reproduce in a crude form without bit shift operators yields strange results:

```
value = 0.4242
bitSh = [256.0*256.0*256.0, 256.0*256.0, 256.0, 1.0]
bitMsk = [0.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0, 1.0/256.0]
res = bitSh.map(function(sh){return (sh*value)%1})
masked = [res[0]*bitMsk[0],res[0]*bitMsk[1],res[1]*bitMsk[2],res[2]*bitMsk[3]]
resres = res.map(function(r,i){return r - masked[i]});
console.log(resres) => [0.0272000003606081, 0.37109375, 0.59375, 0.421875]
```

Btw if I multiply all of those by 255 - `gba` part (of `rgba`) seems to be matching expected result (if rounded) `r` - not. :\

Can you help me understand what's going on here and replicate this in JS?

Comment: Can you give us an example, how a single float value for e.g. `purple` looks like?

Comment: @Psi Hm, let me think about it. Example code is in the shader, so i can't just easely log it out. But i can give you an rgba value corresponding to some arbitrary float, give me a moment...

Comment: Are these valid examples? Does 0.4242 really result in [0,95,151,108] or is this just an example with fictional values?

Comment: @Psi there will be no point in making few examples if they weren't valid =)
So yeah those are valid. I've just hardcoded those float values in shader and read output from image.

Comment: OK, I just asked because that made no sense to me. I was playing around with https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: Hm as i understand floats from your link are not normalized, this function converts normalized floats, i.e 0-1 (not sure if 1 is included or not)

Comment: Must _not_ be included, otherwise you would get a byte value of 256, which exceeds the range. I'm playing around a bit

Comment: Yep, if I'm not mistaken, it _is_ indeed the difference between normalized and unnormalized floats. Obviously, because JavaScript internally uses unnormalized floats, you get differences because of rounding errors.

Comment: @Psi rounding errors shouldnt have any effect here if we are using hardcoded floats lets say 0.4242. Difference between function in my example and you link is that you link accepts any floats and therefore uses some bytes to encode sign and non-floaty part, as i understand, hense the difference in results between it and my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a working port:

```
function packFloatToVec4i(value) {
    value = new Float32Array([value])[0];
    var msk = 1/256;
    var bitSh = [16777216, 65536, 256.0, 1.0];
    var bitMsk = [0.0, msk, msk, msk];
    var shifted = [value*bitSh[0]%1,value*bitSh[1]%1,value*bitSh[2]%1,value*bitSh[3]%1];    
    var masked = [shifted[0]*bitMsk[0],shifted[0]*bitMsk[1],shifted[1]*bitMsk[2],shifted[2]*bitMsk[3]];    
    var res = [Math.round((shifted[0]-masked[0])*255),Math.round((shifted[1]-masked[1])*255),Math.round((shifted[2]-masked[2])*255),Math.round((shifted[3]-masked[3])*255)];
    return res;
};
```

Difference with my attempt posted in question is double - to - float conversion for input value. Without it results were off due to the fact that function was made for float values in GLSL.
Also I've unrolled my .map loops for the sake of performance.

Regarding bitshift operations it seems that internally, in JS, any value to which they are applied - converted to 32bit integer, which effectively removes any fractional info. So bit shift operations doesn't seems to be possible in this case.

Correct me if I'm wrong and bit shifting/masking can be used here, but for now, this will do the trick.